# Svelte return 404 error Not found: /signup Error: Not found: /signup

Tags: visual-studio-code, npm, svelte, sveltekit, custom-error-pages

My project is returning this annoying 404 error when I click on sign up page. No idea what could be.
My main page with the login form, its this one below:

```
<script>
  import supabase  from "$lib/external/supa";
  import { goto } from "$app/navigation";

  let email = "";
  let password = "";

  export let title;

  async function handleLogin() {
    if (title == "Login") {
      const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.signIn({
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
      if (user) {
        goto("/dashboard");
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    } else {
      const { user, error } = await supabase.auth.signUp({
        email: email,
        password: password,
      });
      if (user) {
        goto("/dashboard");
      } else {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
  }
</script>

<div class="loginFormContainer">
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <form class="loginForm" on:submit|preventDefault={handleLogin}>
        <input type="email" bind:value={email} placeholder="email@email.com"/>
        <input type="password" bind:value={password} placeholder="password"/>
        <button type="submit">{title}</button>
    </form>
    <a href="/signup">Not a member? Sign up</a>
</div>
```

When I click on the sign up button, I got the error below:

```
404
Not found: /signup
Error: Not found: /signup
    at resolve (file:///<path>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:326:13)
    at Object.handle (file:///<path>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:319:66)
    at respond (file:///<path>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/index.js:345:30)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async file:///<path>/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:385:22
```

And this mine signup.svelte

```
<script>
  import LoginForm from "$lib/components/loginForm.svelte";
</script>

<div class="container">
  <LoginForm title="Sign Up" />
</div>
```

I'm not an expert on Svelte or in front development, but I think that could be something related to the route, when I inpect the page, I just got

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

I used this video as reference:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3BAuF2XZng

My src/routes:
[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share your `src/routes` structure with us?

Comment: This could just be a typo here, but you've spelt `signup.svelte` as `isgnup.svelte`. Sure you got the filenames right?

Comment: I added my src/routes on the description @phaberest

Comment: @SSBakh I have checked my code few times, and I didn't any typo, besides that on the description

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The routing system has changed in a recent version, now you have to make **one folder per route** so your folder structure would have to be:

```
/src
  /routes
    /dashboard
      +page.svelte
    /signup
      +page.svelte
    +page.svelte
```

Comment: the page name literal "+page.svelte"

Comment: Wait so you are saying if I upgraded svelte my entire application is now broken because they changed how it works? This does not inspire confidence :-)

Comment: It was changed during the pre-release of SvelteKit, so only if you upgraded from a beta version to another beta version you had this issue.  Note that this is also 1.5 years ago, not really relevant for anyone starting now.